# Localization of a javascript objects that has entries in several languages

Tags: javascript, object, localization, iteration

I am struggeling with the following problem:

I want to localize an item that offers content in several languages using a fallback strategy which you can see in pseudo code in the code snippet below: how would I go about this in javascript?

```js
// item is a string similar to this below: where some languages are set others are not
// let item = {'en': 'Good morning', 'de': 'Guten Morgen', 'fr': '', 'it': 'Ciao'};
// locale is a language and in ['de', 'fr', 'en', 'it']

let itemLocalize = function (item, locale) {
   // return item at locale if it is set
   // otherwise return first available language in the order of the array above
}

console.log(itemLocalize(item, 'de'));  // 'Guten Morgen'
console.log(itemLocalize(item, 'fr'));  // 'Good morning'
console.log(itemLocalize(item, 'it'));  // 'Ciao'
console.log(itemLocalize(item, 'en'));  // 'Good morning'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this. Make changes accordingly

```js
let itemLocalize = function (locale) {
  let confirmMessage = {
        'en':'Good Morning',
        'it':'',
        'de':'Guten Morgen',
        'fr': ''
        }

  let arr = ['de', 'fr', 'en', 'it'].find((el) => {
    if (el) {
        return confirmMessage[el];
     }
  });
  
  return confirmMessage[locale] || confirmMessage[arr];
}

console.log(itemLocalize('fr'));
console.log(itemLocalize('en'));
console.log(itemLocalize('it'));
console.log(itemLocalize('de'));
```

Comment: Updated my answer for array priority too. If any locale is not found it will get first from array.